# Send buffer for file in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, discord.js

I know you can send from a filename, but I don't have access to the filesystem because I am using Heroku.

```
client.sendFile(messagedata, writer.toBuffer(), "file.png", "Just a message");
```

The problem is that

```
TypeError: client.sendFile is not a function
```

What equivalent function in discord.js will allow me to send a buffer as a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sendFile()` was deprecated. It's now only [`.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)

To send a file to a User you do:

```
message.author.send({
  files: [{
    attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.jpg',
    name: 'file.jpg'
  }]
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error);
```

To send the file to a Message Channel you can do:

```
message.channel.send({
  files: [{
    attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.jpg',
    name: 'file.jpg'
  }]
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 7):

I know it's old, but here's an example with text, to send a file in channel without using filesystem.

```js
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js')

const buffer = Buffer.from('Text in file')
const attachment = new MessageAttachment(buffer, 'file.txt')
channel.send(attachment)
```